# good use of action cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

I'm starting with rails 6 and action cable, I've been creating channels for the use of action cable and updating the values in one view when they change or are modified in another. But I have one question, is it harmful to create too many channels? I'm creating my commercial application and I have about 25 sections on my page, each section is a CRUD of a different model. To apply action cable to them I must create 25 channels for each model? or would it be affecting the performance of my application by creating so many channels?

Comment: You can do a load test and if there is a performance problem then try to optimize it, but it sounds like your approach makes sense so I wouldn't think there would be any issue. Don't the different channels share a websocket connection? Or do you open multiple websocket connections from the client?

Answer (score 1):

ActionCable channels are just keys in redis backend, they all use the same websocket (if you set it up the recommended way). So this shouldn't affect your apps performance.

But 25 models means 25 [stream_from](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Channel/Streams.html#method-i-stream_from) calls and 25 [subscriptions.create](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#client-server-interactions-subscriptions) calls. This would hurt the productivity of the programmer. I don't know the details of your requirements but I would seek to generalize the updates that gets sent over websockets just to simplify the mental model.